# What is the maximum length of a school bus and trailer combination in California?

Tags: california, vehicle, motor-vehicle

I have a 40 ft school bus rv conversion and am wondering what kind of vehicle this is legally when it comes to towing. I found some good material saying semis and trailers can be at max 65' long (http://www.dot.ca.gov/trafficops/trucks/docs/ca-legal.pdf)

However, I'm not sure if a school bus is in this category or not. If not, what is the max vehicle+trailer length?

EDIT:

School buses do tow trailers...but usually not by school districts. My specific bus has a side exit and is a school bus conversion.

see here for an example of someone else who did this: https://www.pirate4x4.com/forum/tow-rigs-trailers/660797-sxors-blue-bird-bus-hauler.html

Comment: Do they even make school buses that tow trailers? I've never seen one. Usually a school bus has an emergency exit at the rear of the bus that would be obstructed by a trailer. Absent some evidence that such school buses exist, I am inclined to think that this question is asking a non-existent question.

Comment: @ohwilleke Good question. Updated above with an example of someone who did this. There's also a YT video of someone doing the same thing

Comment: So it is a vehicle formerly used as a school bus and perhaps designed for that purpose, not one currently in use to transport school children?

Comment: @ohwilleke Yep! It is currently a Motorhome on the registration.